# Tail recursion in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, tail-recursion

I'm trying to implement merge function in OCaml using Tail recursion but I face awkward results. Could anyone help me out  with this. Thanks in advance.

```
let rec merge_helper l1 l2 accum = 
match l1 with
[] -> l2@accum
| hd::tl -> (match l2 with
    [] -> l1@accum
    |x::xs -> merge_helper tl xs l1@l2@accum);;
let merge l1 l2 = merge_helper l1 l2 [];;

merge [1;2;4] [3;4;5];;
- : int list = [4; 5; 2; 4; 4; 5; 1; 2; 4; 3; 4; 5]
```

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: @AnthonyScemama 1 2 3 4 4 5

Comment: If you want to merge two ordered list, then you need at least one comparison of two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your implementation doesn't run in a constant stack space. The `xs @ ys` operation is not tail-recursive, and will make `List.length xs` calls (thus using this amount of stack frames). Also, the `merge` function usually preserves the ordering. So you need to have a comparison function, that will compare elements of the list. It is not absolutely clear, what you're expecting from you `merge` function, and why you classify your result as weird. For me the result matches with the code. What looks very strange to me is that although you're deconstructing `l1` and `l2` you're not using the result of the deconstruction and adds the whole lists `l1` and `l2` to the accumulator.

The approach should be the following, take an element from the first list, add this element to the accumulator, and switch the lists. So the induction step of the algorithm is the following:

```
 let rec loop acc xs ys = match xs with
   ...
   | x::xs -> loop (x::acc) ys xs
```

But if you want to merge two sorted lists preserving the order, then you need to take the smallest element of the two lists at each step.

```
let merge cmp xs ys = 
    let rec loop xs ys zs = match xs,ys with
      | [],ss|ss,[] -> List.rev_append zs ss
      | x :: txs, y :: tys -> 
         if cmp x y <= 0 
         then loop txs ys (x::zs)
         else loop xs tys (y::zs) in
    loop xs ys []
```

Here in the induction step, we take the smaller element, and continue with the two lists: the tail of the owner of the smaller element (because it is moved into the accumulator), and the second list is taken fully (because nothing is accumulated from it). Since we're prepending elements, they will be in a reversed order, so we will need to something to reverse the result (a usual trade off for tail-recursion). The base case, allows us to short-circuit our algorithm, when one or another list is shorter, and we don't need any more to compare them one-by-one, and can just append the rest part of the longer list to the accumulator `zs`. We use `List.rev_append` to append the leftover tail of the list to our accumulator.  This function will prepend the reversed version of the first list to the second.

Comment: In a merge sort you should alternate between merging the smallest and the largest first and only reveres the end result once if the number of merge steps was uneven. Saves some time and memory.

Comment: yep, it is usually useful to have a more efficient `merge_rev` function available. I wish all list functions had a `?rev` parameter.